# Preseed late_command

Tags: linux, debian-based

I am trying to add a `late_command` to my `preseed.cfg` file but I get following error.

**command:**

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    no_proxy=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 preseed_fetch /scripts/preseed_late_commands.sh /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh ; \
    /target/usr/bin/dos2unix /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh || true; \
    log-output -t preseed_late_commands.sh sh /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh
```

**The error that I get:**

```
Execution of preseeded command "d-i preseed/late_command string \
no_proxy=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 preseed_fetch /scripts/preseed_late_commands.sh /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh ; \
/target/usr/bin/dos2unix /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh || true; \
log-output -t preseed_late_commands.sh sh /tmp/preseed_late_commands.sh" failed with exit code 2.
```

**Infos:**

os: Debian 11 (Bullseye)

`preseed.cfg` directory: `http/d-i/bullseye/preseed.cfg`

`preseed_late_commands.sh` directory: `http/d-i/bullseye/scripts/preseed_late_commands.sh`

**Error image:**

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESRE4.jpg)

What should I do to get this command to run?

How and where can I see a live log (console output) or find a log file?

Comment: Please check your filenames, e.g. `preseed_late_command.sh` vs `preseed_late_commands.sh`. The backslashes look suspicious. Please [edit] your question to fix typos. Copy&paste everything instead of retyping whenever possible. How exactly do you provide the preseed files?

Comment: BTW: This question might better fit on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: Hi @Bodo, I checked and fixed my question's file names and directories. I am gonna try StackExchange and superuser too.

Comment: How exactly do you provide the preseed files? Citing https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed : *As of Debian 10 preseed file can be loaded using these URL schemes: file floppy http https tftp* Unfortunately I don't know where to find the logfile. What's in `preseed_late_commands.sh`? Please don't cross-post the question to multiple sites. If you choose a different site, remove it here. (Questions can be migrated to other sites, but I don't know how to request this.)